# Add an error to the search form

Tags: php

I've tried to add an error to the search form but it doesn't work, if you want see the demo you can go on [Svapomc.com](http://www.svapomc.com/fastdl) , please some one can help me? Thanks a lot

```
    </html>
<head>
    <link href="cerca.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="" method="get">

    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Cerca la mappa da scaricare (può essere pure incompleto)"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Cerca"/>

    </form>
<body>

</html>

<?php
//--- get all the directories
$search = $_GET["search"];
$dirname = 'maps';
$findme  = "*.bz2";
$dirs    = glob($dirname.'*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
$files   = array();
//--- search through each folder for the file
//--- append results to $files
foreach( $dirs as $d ) {
    $f = glob( $d .'/'. $findme );
    if( count( $f ) ) {
        $files = array_merge( $files, $f );
    }
}
if( count($files) ) {
    foreach( $files as $f ) {
        if(strpos($f, $search) !== false and strpos($f, '.nav') === false and strpos($f, '.jpg') === false and strpos($f, '.txt') === false and strpos($f, '.jpe') === false or !isset($_GET["search"]) or $search == ""){
            $f1 = str_replace('maps/', '', $f);
            $f1 = str_replace('.bz2', '', $f1);
            $f1 = str_replace('.bsp', '', $f1);
            echo "<div class='ciao'><p>{$f1} <a download href='{$f}'>Download</a></p></div><br>";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "<p>Error message here</p>";
}
?>
```

This is all the code i think the problem is in the else but i don't know

Comment: What's not working? You get a php-error? You don't see the image when you should? You get the downloadlink but expect the errormessage?

Comment: Check what is your count. if( count($files)>0 ) {

Comment: no i want see the error message when i press send and if the file doesn't exist the site tell you: the file doesn't exist or something like this

Comment: i doesn't have anithing like if(count($files)>0 ) where i need to add this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you have files, but no match ...

```
$file_found = false;
if( count($files) ) {
    foreach( $files as $f ) {
        if(strpos($f, $search) !== false and strpos($f, '.nav') === false and strpos($f, '.jpg') === false and strpos($f, '.txt') === false and strpos($f, '.jpe') === false or !isset($_GET["search"]) or $search == ""){
            $f1 = str_replace('maps/', '', $f);
            $f1 = str_replace('.bz2', '', $f1);
            $f1 = str_replace('.bsp', '', $f1);
            echo "<div class='ciao'><p>{$f1} <a download href='{$f}'>Download</a></p></div><br>";
            $file_found = true;
        }
    }
}

if(!$file_found){
    echo "<p>Non è stata trovata nessuna mappa con questo nome</p>";
    echo '<img src="yourimagehere.jpg"/>';
}
```

Comment: No sorry dude it works i've failed to copy the code thank you very much